# Extract case class field name in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a case class:

```
case class A(field1: String, field2: Int)
```

I want to refer to the exact string "field1" in some code something like:

```
val q = Query("field1"-> "hello")
performQuery(q)
```

Now I have to be careful that I type "field1" correctly all the time. To avoid that, I want to use a reference to `A.field1` as a string, something like this:

```
val q = Query(A.field1 -> "hello")
performQuery(q)
```

This will help me avoid any typing mistake, and also if I later rename those fields, I don't need to update rest of the codebase strings. I can rely on IDE for that.

How can I extract a case class field name as string?

**EDIT1**

Here is another variation of the usage:

```
// capture the field name
val FIELD1_NAME = A.field1 // this implementation can change
```

At this point `FIELD1_NAME` should contain `"field1"` as string

```
// Now use the string obtained above to create a query:
val q = Query(FIELD1_NAME -> "hello")
performQuery(q)
```

Comment: It doesn't look good as `A` itself is a companion object in your context that does not have this field `field1`, even if it had it would evaluate to the contents of this field. I am guessing that if it's possible, you need macros.

Comment: @Łukasz I thought of macros too. However I don't have enough expertise with macros to proceed forward. What would be good approach to achieve what I descried ?

Comment: The thing is I don't have either :D we need to wait.

Comment: Well, the macros still need to typecheck before they are expanded, and `A.field1` won't. What about `Query[A](_.field1 -> "hello")`?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I updated the question to clarify that it is not restricted to `A.field1` in any way. We can use any approach as long as we can extract field1 within the Scala code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found at https://gist.github.com/dwickern/b47606a1ed2319afa6e2:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Macros {
  def nameOfImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(x: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    @tailrec def extract(x: c.Tree): String = x match {
      case Ident(TermName(s)) => s
      case Select(_, TermName(s)) => s
      case Function(_, body) => extract(body)
      case Block(_, expr) => extract(expr)
      case Apply(func, _) => extract(func)
    }

    val name = extract(x)
    q"$name"
  }
  def nameOfMemberImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(f: c.Tree): c.Tree = nameOfImpl(c)(f)

  def nameOf(x: Any): String = macro nameOfImpl
  def nameOf[T](f: T => Any): String = macro nameOfMemberImpl
}

//
// Sample usage:
//

val someVariable = ""
Macros.nameOf(someVariable) // "someVariable"

def someFunction(x: Int): String = ???
Macros.nameOf(someFunction _) // "someFunction"

case class SomeClass(someParam: String)
val myClass = SomeClass("")
Macros.nameOf(myClass.someParam) // "someParam"

// without having an instance of the class:
Macros.nameOf[SomeClass](_.someParam) // "someParam"
```

For your use-case, `Query(nameOf[A](_.field1) -> "hello")`.