# Runtime reflection - extracting Symbols using a single method

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I need to extract the Symbols of some types and terms, and currently I am doing it as in the following:

```
val assetElem     = Asset(typeOf[Display].member(TermName("kindOfDisplay")).asMethod)
val assetElem_2   = Asset(typeOf[Heat].typeSymbol)
val assetElem_3   = Asset(typeOf[Temperature.type].termSymbol)
```

Is there a way how I can optimize this code by creating a generic method which I can use by only giving as its parameter the type in "typeOf"?

Something like

```
def asset[T](s: T): Symbol = typeOf[T].typeSymbol
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need a `TypeTag[T]`:

```
def typeSymbol[T: TypeTag]: Symbol = typeOf[T].typeSymbol

typeSymbol[Heat]
```

Comment: thanks for guiding me to the `TypeTag`-s, I am checking them, but I needed to include all three cases (from the given examples) in that way that I can write: `typeSymbol[Heat]` when the `Heat` is a class name, or `typeSymbol[Temperature]` when `Temperature` is an object, or `typeSymbol[kindOfDisplay]` when `kindOfDisplay` is a method...

Comment: Neither `Temperature` nor `kindOfDisplay` can be type parameters, because they aren't types. For `Temperature`, you could use `typeSymbol[Temperature.type]` and modify the body to treat `SingletonType`s specially. For `kindOfDisplay`, I don't think you can get closer than `asset[Display](_.kindOfDisplay)`, if that's acceptable, my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723968/extract-case-class-field-name-in-scala/36725367#36725367 should be easy to modify.